# How to filter null value in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I want to filter the records that *COMMENTS* attribute is null

[image]

I have tried

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COMMENTS FROM 
    (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COMMENTS FROM (select * FROM user_tab_comments))
    WHERE COMMENTS != null;
```

But it didn't return the right output. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NULL` is a state not a value, therefore you can't use normal operators on it. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` instead.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COMMENTS 
  FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COMMENTS FROM (select * FROM user_tab_comments))
    WHERE COMMENTS IS NOT NULL;
```

Just saw that you don't need all those subqueries

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COMMENTS 
  FROM user_tab_comments 
 WHERE COMMENTS IS NOT NULL;
```